# In which format are images gathered from the getUser function from the kik API

Tags: kik

With the functions

```
kik.photo.get(options, callback)

kik.photo.getFromCamera(options, callback)

kik.photo.getFromGallery(options, callback)
```

I can receive photos in Data URL Format.

I also can receive the profile picture and thumbnail with

```
kik.getUser()
```

However the documentation ( http://dev.kik.com/docs/ ) doesn`t state in which format the images are received using this function and it doesn't seem to be Data-URL, so my question is.

**In which format are thumbnail and profile pictures returned when using the `kik.getUser()` function.**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It returns a URL to an image hosted on a CDN (not a data URI). That images on the CDN are jpeg-encoded